# Matching Java DecimalNumeral using possessive regex operators

Tags: java, regex, backtracking

A Java decimal number should start with a non-zero digit, followed by any number of digits or underscore, and finally end with a digit. We can write the following regular expression to capture them:

```
[1-9][0-9_]*[0-9]
```

(Note that this not the complete regex, there are two more alternatives that are not relevant for this question: [0] | [1-9][0-9]*)

This regular expression works and it's fine. However, since * is greedy, it does backtracking, in this case at least always one character back to match the last digit. Is there any way to rewrite this example using possessive * (*+) that does not use backtracking? Or is there any equivalent regular expression that does not require backtracking? Use of other advanced features such as lookahead, etc is fine, I just don't want backtracking.

PS. I know many of you might think that the performance of * compared to *+ is not a real problem and why I need this, but I'm not concerned about performance. I'm wondering if a deterministic version of this regular expression exists.

Comment: `0` and any one digit number are valid decimal numbers not matched by your regexp.

Comment: Maybe `[1-9][0-9_]*+(?<!_)` can be of help with just 1 backtracking step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the state machine for the regular expression you want (final state is 1):

```
on    | transitions
------+--------------
[1-9] | 0-1
[0-9] | 1-1, 2-1
_     | 1-2, 2-2
```

And the regular expression:

```
[1-9](?:_*[0-9])*
```

It does not match `0` though, as the expression you provided.